# Type error: when trying to remove '\n' from the created list

Tags: python, list, concatenation, typeerror

I am trying to remove '\n' from the the list i created eg: find\n to find
but it is in list.
I am new to python tring to learn by online course and i am tring to create a program for TODO List
I have encounter this error.

```
while True:
    user_action = input("Type add,show,exit,edit,complete: ")
    user_action = user_action.strip()

    if 'add' in user_action:
        todo = user_action[4:].title() + "\n"
        with open('todos.txt', 'r') as file:
            todos = file.readlines()

        todos.append(todo)
        with open('todos.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.writelines(todos)

    elif 'show' in user_action:
        with open('todos.txt', 'r') as file:
            todos = file.readlines()

        for index, item in enumerate(todos):
            new_item = item.strip()
            row = f"{index + 1}-{new_item}"
            print(row)
    elif 'edit' in user_action:
        user_input =int(user_action[5:])

        user_value = user_input - 1
        with open('todos.txt', 'r') as file:
            todos = file.readlines()
            print("here is you existing todo", todos + '\n')

        todos[user_value] = input("Enter a new todo:").title() + '\n'
        with open('todos.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.writelines(todos)
    elif 'complete' in user_action:
        user_input = int(input("Enter a number to complete todo: "))
        with open('todos.txt', 'r') as file:
            todos = file.readlines()
        index = user_input - 1
        todo_to_remove = todos[index].strip()

        with open('todos.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.writelines(todos)
            todos.pop(index)
        with open('todos.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.writelines(todos)
        message = f"This todo will be removed:{todo_to_remove}"
        print(message)
    elif 'exit' in user_action:
        print("Bye!")
        break
    else:
        print("Check and type again ")
print("Bye !")
```

That code produce the following error:

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\awani\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 28, in <module>
    print("here is you existing todo", todos + '\n')
                                       ~~~~~~^~~~~~
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list**
```

I am trying to to remove '\n' from the list i created.
eg: human\n
to
human

Comment: If you're trying to _remove_ the newline, why would you use `+ '\n'` which **adds** a newline?

Answer (score 2):

this may be helpful for you.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-removing-newline-character-from-string/
Below is a part from the above link

```
enter code here

# initialize list
test_list = ['gf\ng', 'i\ns', 'b\nest', 'fo\nr', 'geeks\n']

# printing original list
print("The original list : " + str(test_list))

# Removing newline character from string
# using loop
res = []
for sub in test_list:
    res.append(sub.replace("\n", ""))

# printing result
print("List after newline character removal : " + str(res))  

Output:
The original list : ['gf\ng', 'i\ns', 'b\nest', 'fo\nr', 'geeks\n']
List after newline character removal : ['gfg', 'is', 'best', 'for','geeks']
```

Dimitris

Answer (score 1):

`file` is an object that can be iterated over to get each line one by one.

Well, there are many ways to resolve your problem. For example, we can write a list comprehension like this :

```py
tasks = [task.strip() for task in file]
```

I think it is the most pythonic code we can do in this situation.
Your code become :

```py
with open('todos.txt', 'r') as file:
    tasks = [task.strip() for task in file]
    print("here is you existing todo", *tasks)
```

To explain you, `*tasks` take `tasks` and unpack it like `tasks[0], tasks[1], ..., tasks[-1]`.

In fact, `print("here is you existing todo", *tasks)` is exactly the same that

```py
print("here is you existing todo", tasks[0], tasks[1], ..., tasks[-1])
```

and the separator (by default a single space) is beetween all arguments in the output.

I hope I answered your question.

Comment: I disagree with "most pythonic". For me it would be more pythonic to remove the line with the call to `readlines` and to use `tasks = [task.strip() for task in file]` in the following line instead.

Comment: It's true ! oops... corrected !